# How to find inlet and outlet nodes in undirected networkX graph of complicated skeleton of pathes in porous structure?

Tags: python, graph, python-3.6, networkx, undirected-graph

**Hello!** 
I have a networkX graph of skeleton of inner space in porous structure. I need to calculate lengths of paths between the inlet and outlet nodes. In order to do it I consider nodes with z coordinate more/less than certain number (lower and upper black lines) and if they has paths between each other I calculate them. But with that approach I calculate almost the same paths several times because I don't know how to define only inlet (or outlet).

[image: I consider all the nodes lower and upper black lines]

Comment: Can you show us some code, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be enough to

- grab a list of possible inlet nodes (z>450)
- grab a list of possible outlet nodes (z<50)
- compute all the combinations of input/output nodes (`itertools.product`) and stash them into a dict mapping pairs to paths (`dict.fromkeys(combinations, None)`)
- for each combination:

  - compute whether a path is found (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html)
  - if a path is not found, mark it so in the dict
  - if a path is found:

    - mark it in the dict for the input/output pair
    - if the path contains an input/output node combination that you haven't yet computed (the value in the dict is None), the same path (or a subset thereof) will apply for that combination too

Comment: I would just add to this that inlet and outlet node candidates furthermore have the property that they have a node degree of 1 (i.e. they are a leaf in the graph) -- accessible via `nx.Graph.degree`.

Comment: I did the combinations feature and it worked for me! Also thank you for node degree information, I didn't know about it.